# Simple elegant way to put a button on a rails view that calls a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a helper method that helps log my app in as a client to trello using gems.

```
require 'oauth'
require 'trello'

module TrelloHelper
  def connect
    ...
  end
  def board
    ...
  end
end
```

I just want to include this in an erb template in the views and have it run when I click a button.

For instance, I click the button it calls

```
TrelloHelpers::connect
```

That method gets my oauth keys configures the Trello client and redirects to the auth page for my Trello account. I already have that method set up. How do I make it so that it is triggered by a button on the view.

I have seen other solutions that use Ajax, POSTs, endpoints and routing, but how can I just call a method with a button click?

Can I just make my method return a URL and then use a link_to in the template? What would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the button in a form pointing to an action in a controller. The controller should include that helper, and then in the action corresponding to form I would simply call the method from the helper.

This way, when the user clicks a button a form is submitted, which then triggers your controller's action, and your action will execute the helper method.

Comment: Sounds good. I wanted something simpler, but I already know how to do this from reading tutorials. I'll try it l out, and if I'm still curious I'll try for a refactor. Thanks!